# Reference Book- Stochastic Games

Tags: probability, game-theory, book-recommendation

Any suggestions for an introductory book on Stochastic Games.

Answer (score 0):

Filar, Jerzy, and Koos Vrieze. **Competitive Markov decision processes**. Springer-Verlag New York, 1997.

Comment: The publishing date is 1997.

Comment: @mlc indeed, corrected.